# Cannot create directory but files

Tags: java, android, file-io

Here are things I have done:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

and

```
public void createMyFolder(){
   File directory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/myfolder/");
   directory.mkdir(); //I had also tried mkdirs()

   File file= new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/t1.dat");
   try {
      file.createNewFile();
   } catch (IOException e) {}
}
```

I tested 3 devices and one of them threw exception:

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot create dir /mnt/sdcard/myfolder
```

t1.dat was created successfully in /mnt/sdcard/ but myfolder was not.

The device is Xperia Ion with Android version 4.0.4. What's wrong about it and how can I fix it?

---

**Edit**: I had tried to create folders by some applications, like File Manager.
And they also failed to create although the sdcard is writable and readable.
I think my phone has some "protections" which do not allow me to create folders in sd card.
But it's funny that my phone allows me to create files instead.

```
public boolean isExternalStorageWritable() {
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

/* Checks if external storage is available to at least read */
public boolean isExternalStorageReadable() {
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state) ||
            Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Try just "myfolder/" instead of "/myfolder/"
That may or may not help, but it's worth checking

Answer (score 0):

Replace Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() with directory and also "/myfolder" will be "/myfolder"

```
  public void createMyFolder(){
        File directory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/myfolder");
        directory.mkdir(); //I had also tried mkdirs()

        File file= new File(directory.getPath() + "/t1.dat");
        try {
            file.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {}
    }
```